# Mbed wrong long int parsing

Tags: c++, mbed

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        const char* s = "Number: 420604953084";
        long number;
        sscanf(s, "Number: %ld", &number);
        printf("Result: %ld", number);

        return 0;
    }
```

This code, compiled on desktop with c++11 (or, for example [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)) returns correctly:

```
Result: 420604953084
```

But compiled with ARM Mbed 6.6 the result is:

```
(#include <mbed.h>)
...
Result: -301941924
```

Does anyone have a clue? Unforunatelly, these things are not documented at all in Mbed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your the *long* type is 4 Bytes on your compiler. I think it's reasonable to get and error.

Please try *unsigned long long* and the format code *"lld"*.